# Open another FancyBox from callbackOnShow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am using this http://fancybox.net/

I have 2 `div`s: 1st open and 2nd hidden

In the first `FancyBox`, I want to run several things in `callbackOnShow`
and then once done, it closes and opens the second hidden `Fancybox`.
However I used `$('a#div-2').trigger('click');` and it is not working.
It seems that the `FancyBox` trigger won't allow within `callbackOnShow`.
If I do that trigger when document ready, the second box shows.

Any help on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delay the opening - [How do I open one Fancybox after another closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715986/how-do-i-open-one-fancybox-after-another-closes)  I might try to add a callback for when the fancybox FINISHES closing and submit it to fancybox.  I'll let you know