# How do I chain multiple jquery fancyboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox for modals in my web application.

There are cases when I'd like to popup a 2nd fancybox while one is already opened.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?  I'm ok with one opening after the other closes, or both being open at the same time one underneath the other.

Again, i'm using jquery and fancybox in my application.

Comment: If your not tied down to Fancybox in particular http://highslide.com/ this one does that job by default. Try opening several on the homepage

Comment: Highslide does look to be nice, but I'm trying to keep this free.  It does however do what i'm needing.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good relevant thread discussing the same thing.. [How do I open one Fancybox after another closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715986/how-do-i-open-one-fancybox-after-another-closes)

EDITED:
In the discussion, there is a good example provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/139396/o-k-w

I have placed the example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CkK8N/

Comment: Hi, I'm a Stack Overflow moderator. Please at _least_ summarize the information in your link, or delete this and post it as a comment. If that link breaks, so does your answer. Even if you are linking to an answer on SO, please provide context. Questions and answers _do_ get deleted from time to time.

Comment: Additionally, a good question to ask is "If this page were printed, would this answer still be useful?"

Answer (score 1):

I've just tackled this problem myself.

Scenario:

- Launching one fancybox using an iframe
- From the opened fancybox, open another fancybox with content delivered by an ajax webservice.

Key points

- If using fancybox and iframes, you need to use parent.$.fancybox, otherwise $.fancybox will do.
- Don't forget to show activity before loading content
- Don't forget to resize after loading the content

Code snippet:

```
        if (parent) {
        // if in an iframe we need to show activity for the parents' fancybox
        parent.$.fancybox.showActivity();
    }
    else {
        // otherwise show activity for the fancybox of the current window
        $.fancybox.showActivity();
    }       

            // I'm using Ajax to fetch the content but you can fetch it in other ways too
    $.ajax({
        url: "your url goes here",
        type: "POST",
        contenttype: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: { "name": "john"},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if (parent) {                   
                // if in an iframe we need to push the content into the parents' fancybox
                parent.$.fancybox($(jqXHR.responseXML).text());
                parent.$.fancybox.resize();
            }
            else {
                // otherwise push the content into the fancybox of the current window
                $.fancybox($(jqXHR.responseXML).text());
                $.fancybox.resize();
            }

        }
    });
```