# fancybox, login and reset password forms

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

If i have a login form with a link to new new password form

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
 ''
   <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" name="loginSubmit" value="ok">
</form>
<a href="recoverpw.php"  id="usrFormFancyBox" 
    onClick="$.fancybox(this); return false;">New password</a>
```

And recoverpw.php looks like

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="newPw" id="newPw">
 ''
   <input type="submit" id="resetPw" name="resetPw" value="ok">
</form>
```

that i also to show in the same fancybox. How to close the fancybox while pressing both login submit or a resset password submit?
How to put a correct onClick code? onClick="$.fancybox(this); return false;" or onClick="parent.$.fancybox.close();parent.$.fancybox(this); return false;" or something??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You shall use `setTimeout` and `callbackOnClose` take a look for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715986/how-do-i-open-one-fancybox-after-another-closes) there is a full answer to your question.

Comment: just for the record, `callbackOnClose` is not a valid option in the latest versions of fancybox (v1.3.4 or v2.x). Check the proper documentation for the version you are using.

Comment: Yeah, it seems they changed name of callback property to `onClosed`. Thanks to @JFK