# Using more than one Fancybox Ajax calls on page

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have this code:

```
<a class="fancybox-ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="www.someurl.com">Some content</a>  
<a class="fancybox-ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="www.someurl.com">Some content</a>  
<a class="fancybox-ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="www.someurl.com">Some content</a>
<a class="fancybox-ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="www.someurl.com">Some content</a>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(".fancybox-ajax").fancybox({  
        type: 'ajax',  
        width:800,  
        height: 'auto'  
    });
</script>
```

And it works fine on the first click, however if I click any of the other elements, it produces kinda duplicate content, and clicking further elements just makes it worse. How to fix it?

**UPDATE**
This happens if there's only one trigger, as well. Click the trigger, close fancybox, click the trigger again -> bug.

Answer (score -1):

you need to assign a different rel attribute to each anchor.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" href="product01/image01.jpg">one</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery02" href="product01/image02.jpg">one</a>
```

and they can use same scirpt.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

Comment: but I don't have any galleries, it's an ajax call?

Comment: hmm, i see.. no further answer but i guess this link can help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715986/how-do-i-open-one-fancybox-after-another-closes correctly close one and then use another

Comment: I'm not doing the same thing as that guy, I properly close the first fancybox window, and then click on another link when the box is closed.. but thanks for trying to help mate

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION:** The content being returned by AJAX had the same fancybox call as the original page (universal footer), so hence fancybox was called twice. So, my bug.